# Attaching to AssemblyResolve earlier

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, assemblyresolve

Consider the following code inside of the `Program` class:

```
static EmbeddedClass MyClass;

static Program()
{
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
}

static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    //Load EmbeddedClass here
}
```

For this application we need the assembly `EmbeddedClass` is inside of to be embedded inside the application and not alongside it as a dll. So too load the assembly we need to use `AssemblyResolve`.

However, the above code will not work because upon running it gives:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'Program' threw an exception.

I believe this is because it is trying to load the `EmbeddedClass`'s assembly before it runs the static constructor.

Is there anyway to solve this situation?

Comment: Do you need to have the variable declaration within the `Programm` class?
When you try to move the declaration and usage in another class and call it after you attached the event handler, it might work.

Comment: @ToniWenzel For this particular case it needs to be inside this class. As a workaround I could make them all instance variables but I was trying to avoid that if possible.